# How to receive JSON object from a webworker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Hi am stuck in a problem for retrieving a JSON object from a web worker, I am able to receive something like [object Object] which is not a JSON object.
Following is my code.

main.js file

```
if (window.Worker) { // Check if Browser supports the Worker api.
    var worker;
    try {
         worker = new Worker("worker-data.js");
         worker.postMessage([{"data": [{"data1":30},{"data2":40},{"data3":3}]}]);
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

worker-data.js file code

```
onmessage = function(message) {
    console.log(message.data);
}
```

Output I receive:-
[image: [object Object]]
Output Expected:-
[image: A JSON OBJECT]
sorry for the image alignment.

Comment: by the way, you're posting an object, there's no such thing as a JSON object in javascript ... JSON is a string

Comment: That is just how the console is displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of object inside your post message

```
worker.postMessage([{"data": [{"data1":30},{"data2":40},{"data3":3}]}]);
```

Your array of object is there inside the data property of the message
`message.data`
but you are accessing it all wrong, Try accessing the first index of `message.data`

`message.data[0]` which contains your object `{"data": [{"data1":30},{"data2":40},{"data3":3}]}`

Use `message.data[0].data` to access the data of your object

`[{"data1":30},{"data2":40},{"data3":3}]`

**Explanation:**

whatever you pass in your `worker.postMessage` will be there in `message.data` along with other properties of `message` and here what you passed is an array so you need to access the first index of the array to get your data

`message.data[0]` and then access the data of your object passed `message.data[0].data`

Inside your message

```
 onmessage = function(message) {
    console.log(message.data[0].data);
    console.log(message.data[0].data[0].data1);
    console.log(message.data[0].data[1].data2);
    console.log(message.data[0].data[2].data3); 
 };
```

**or**

Pass only object

`worker.postMessage({"data": [{"data1":30},{"data2":40},{"data3":3}]});`

then on your message access the data as `message.data.data`

```
onmessage = function(message) {
        console.log(message.data.data);
        console.log(message.data.data[0].data1);
        console.log(message.data.data[1].data2);
        console.log(message.data.data[2].data3); 
     };
```

Here is your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d7b680je/1/

**SNIPPET**

*Check the console of snippet for output.*

```js
try {

  var ww = document.querySelector('script[type="text/ww"]'),
    code = ww.textContent,
    blob = new Blob([code], {
      type: 'text/javascript'
    }),
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobUrl);
  let temp = {
    "dataVal": [{
      "data1": 30
    }, {
      "data2": 40
    }, {
      "data3": 3
    }, {
      "data4": 10
    }, {
      "data5": 130
    }, {
      "data6": 140
    }]
  };
  worker.postMessage(temp);

} catch (ex) {
  alert(ex);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/ww">
  self.onmessage = function(message) { console.log(message.data.dataVal); console.log(message.data.dataVal[0].data1); console.log(message.data.dataVal[1].data2); console.log(message.data.dataVal[2].data3); };
</script>
```

**I recommend you remove all arrays and pass your data as objects**

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d7b680je/2/

```js
try {

  var ww = document.querySelector('script[type="text/ww"]'),
    code = ww.textContent,
    blob = new Blob([code], {
      type: 'text/javascript'
    }),
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    worker = new Worker(blobUrl);
  let temp = {
    "dataVal": {
      "data1": 30,
      "data2": 40,
      "data3": 3,
      "data4": 10,
      "data5": 130,
      "data6": 140
    }
  };
  worker.postMessage(temp);

} catch (ex) {
  alert(ex);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/ww">
   self.onmessage = function(message) {
        console.log(message.data.dataVal.data1);
        console.log(message.data.dataVal.data2);
        console.log(message.data.dataVal.data3); 
     };
</script>
```

**Console log of above snippet and fiddle in mac safari**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it dosent solve the problem, the responce is same as provided.

Comment: worker.postMessage *should* be able to accept an object! So, no need to create JSON string ... `JSON string instead of JSON object` ... no such thing as a JSON object in javascript... it's an object ... that's all, nothing JSON about it

Comment: Thanks for the solution but still it dosn't solve the problem.

Comment: its the same [object Object]

Comment: After using your code I am getting [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: https://cg6.tutorialspoint.com/share/259/Ds6gLNET check this one.

You have array inside your object

Comment: Thanks for your help can you please tell me how i can run it ? cg6.tutorialspoint.com/share/259/Ds6gLNET

Comment: Open the link you click on preview

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle please have a look, i dont know how this fiddle is working correctly.   https://jsfiddle.net/Vaibhav34/d7b680je/

Comment: When i run the same code in chrome its working as expected but in safari its not behaving correctly. Can any one help ?

Comment: Yeah your fiddle is working cause you are creating an blob url to the worker

Comment: How it is behaving in safari

Comment: like this [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Thanks for your help but if i ran the same jsfiddle in safari i receive  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] . Wired behaviour.

Comment: its okay to get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] you are passing array of object

Comment: Copy my code from 2nd snippet/ 2nd jsfiddle and try running it

Comment: its working in chrome browser thanks but not in safari

Comment: @Vaibhav its working in safari check my screenshot in answer from safari

Comment: @Vaibhav care for an upvote  if the answer was helpful !

Comment: Yes jsfiddle link is working in safari, sorry for late reply

Answer (score -2):

JSON.stringify() is used to convert a value to a valid JSON string. Then on the other side you can JSON.parse() to get back the original value.
[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: This is not the problem.